# Should I use #End Robots# or not in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

Should I use #End Robots# or not in robots.txt?

I mean does it help to prevent me from getting whitespaces or not?

right now it looks something like that:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /account/
Disallow: /access-denied/
#End Robots#
```

Comment: Lines starting with `#` are comments and therefor ignored by robots.txt parsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449 seems to suggest that it isn't needed.

Personally I've never added that to any robots file I've deployed and I've never encountered any problems.